# Git post-receive hook fails : operation not allowed

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I have a post-receive hook that call a bash script of mine (which will pull the local repo and restart the Java server).

Here's the owner info of the post-receive hook :

```
-rwsr-x--x 1 cyril devs   676 19 dec.  14:45 post-receive
```

As you can see, I set the `setuid bit` on this script in order to be run as `cyril/devs` also for other users.

The content of this script is rather simple :

```
echo "Running post-receive hook"
echo "Server will be up and running in about 1 minute"
/home/project/start_dev restart &
```

My script `start_dev` has those rights :

```
-rwsr-x---  1 cyril devs 1515 19 dec.  14:41 start_dev
```

Note: also the `setuid.`

If I push something to the server with the account `cyril`, it works perfectly.

If someone else, with an other account, push to the server, they got :

```
remote: /home/project/start_dev: line 52: kill: (11490) - Operation not allowed
```

*(The kill is used to stop the instance.)*

Why they have this errors, the script should be run as `cyril`, not the user, thus they should have the right to kill this instance, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently most Linux distributions disable `setuid` for shell scripts because of the massive security holes it can cause.  More info [here](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html) and from the [setuid Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_on_executables).

> While the setuid feature is very useful in many cases, its improper use can pose a security 
>   risk if the setuid attribute is assigned to executable programs that are not carefully 
>   designed. Due to potential security issues, many operating systems ignore the setuid 
>   attribute when applied to executable shell scripts.

One possible solution from the Tuxation page is to do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   setuid( 0 );
   system( "/path/to/script.sh" );

   return 0;
}
```

Then `setuid` the resulting C program and use that as your hook.  There's also this commentary after that on the Tuxation page though:

> With all that said, running shell scripts with setuid isn't very safe, and the distro 
>   designers had a pretty good idea of what they were doing when many of them disabled it.

Comment: Added solution from Tuxation.